# Oracle Database Connection issue with SSH Tunnel - Logon denied

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ssh-tunnel

We are not able to connect to Oracle DB using SSH Tunnel(set up in putty) from our system command prompt. It is failing with below error:

```
C:\Users\yadavvin>tnsping APPSP
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 16-OCT-2019 11:54:54
Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
sed parameter files:
C:\Oracle\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact **(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = appsp)))**
OK (130 msec)
C:\Users\yadavvin>
C:\Users\yadavvin>sqlplus arpadmin/password@appsp
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Oct 16 11:55:48 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
**ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**
Enter user-name:
C:\Users\yadavvin>
```

However, the same credentials are working with the same SSH Tunnel when connected using SQL DEVELOPER.

Would appreciate any pointers towards resolution of this issue.

```
Oracle DB Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle Client Version: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production
```

Adding the full qualified Database string in SQLPLUS and checking the connection:

```
C:\Users\yadavvin>sqlplus arpadmin/Welc0me2abcr@127.0.0.1:1521/AVSAPPSP

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Oct 16 14:49:50 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: the most likely reason you're getting that is because you're not talking to the same database OR you're not typing in the username/password correctly. that's really the only reason possible - unless it's a AS SYSDBA type user in SQLDev, then you'd need that same string for sqlplus

Comment: try a full EZCONNECT string in sqlplus, so do like sqlplus user/password@server:port/service - that way you don't have to rely on the tns entry being correct

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, we have tried per your suggestion and got the above error.

Comment: then your connect string is wrong, or that db doesn't exist where you think it does